# $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+2 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

If $R=\mathbb{R}[x]$ is the polynomial ring with real coefficients and$\ I=\langle x^2+1 \rangle,\ J=\langle x^2+2 \rangle$ two ideals of $R$ we want to show that $R/I \cong R/J$ and $I\neq J$.

*Answer:* If we define a function $φ:\mathbb{R}[x] \longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $f(x) \mapstoφ(f(x))=f(i)$ then $φ$ is well defined, homomorphism, surjective ($Imφ=\mathbb{C}$) and with kernel $Kerφ=\langle x^2+1 \rangle$. So, from the fundamental isomorphism theorem $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{C}. $ Similarly , if we define another function $ψ:\mathbb{R}[x] \longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $f(x) \mapstoψ(f(x))=f(\sqrt {2}i)$, then we have the same with he case before, but with $Kerψ=\langle x^2+2 \rangle$ and  $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{C}. $ And that means that $R/I \cong R/J$.

If $I=J\iff \langle x^2+1 \rangle = \langle x^2+2 \rangle$ then:

1. $x^2+1 \in \langle x^2+2 \rangle \iff x^2+1=q(x)(x^2+2), q(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]\implies degq(x)=0 \implies q(x)=α \in \mathbb{R}^*. $

   So, $x^2+1=α(x^2+2) \iff α=1$ and $α=1/2$, contradiction.
2. $x^2+2 \in \langle x^2+1 \rangle \iff x^2+2=r(x)(x^2+1), q(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]\implies degr(x)=0 \implies r(x)=β \in \mathbb{R}^*. $
   So, $x^2+2=β(x^2+1) \iff β=1$ and $β=2$, contradiction.

From 1., 2. we conclude that $Ι\neq J$. Right?

*I know that the first part has already asked, so I wrote it in a few words, to emphisize on the second part*.

Comment: second part seems fine, but you only need either 1 or 2, not both. Of course both is not wrong, just redundant. 1 for example already shows $I\not\subset J$ so surely $I\not=J$

Comment: @user2520938 Yes you are right. Any other ways to prove it?

Comment: @Chris Note that $I=J$ iff there exist $f(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ such that $x^2+1=f(x)(x^2+2)$.Do you see that $i$ is a root of LHS but not of RHS?Hence conclude.

Comment: @Dontknowanything So $f(i)=0$. But if we take the degrees $f(x)=c \neq 0$. Contradiction.

Comment: If $I = J$, then $x^2 + 1 \in I$ and $x^2 + 2 \in I$, so then $1 \in I$.